# Remote SSH without reentering Password

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to loop through a list of remote servers, ssh to them and get hardware info, but this requires sudo password, and I don't want to have to type in password for each loop, and unsure how to accomplish that. My script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat server-list.txt); do 
    ssh -t username@${i} 'sudo -s <dmidecode -t 1>';
done
```

Note: all system commands require sudo password.

Comment: You can use sshpass - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454037/pass-a-password-to-ssh-in-pure-bash

Comment: Appreciate your response. I'll give that a try.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310299/proper-way-to-sudo-over-ssh/53189456#53189456