# How to hide the system call passed in the system() function from htop

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

Consider this C snippet:

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "<LONG PROCESS WITH PARAMETERS HAVING SENSITIVE INFO>";
system(buf);
```

Now on compiling and executing this, the "sensitive" parameters of the process can be seen on programs like `htop`
And I don't want that.

I would like to know if there's a way to hide everything passed in `system()` such that `htop` will only show the name of the compiled executable (i.e htop just displays `a.out` all the time)

Comment: you could use a wrapper which reads an environment variable instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding secret from command line parameter on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830823/hiding-secret-from-command-line-parameter-on-unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all the Unix-like systems I've used, including many Linux variants, it's possible for a program to overwrite it's command-line arguments "from inside". So in C we might use, for example, `strcnpy()` just to blank the values of `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, etc. Of course, you need to have processed or copied these arguments first, and you need to be careful not to overwrite memory outside the specific limits of each `argv`.

I don't think anything about Unix guarantees the portability or continued applicability of this approach, but I have been using it for at least twenty years. It conceals the command from casual uses of `ps`, etc., and also from `/proc/NN/cmdline`, but it won't stop the shell storing the command line somewhere (e.g., in a shell history file). So it only prevents casual snooping.

A better approach is not to get into the situation in the first place -- have the program take its input from files (which could be encrypted), or environment variables, or use certificates. Or almost anything, in fact, except the command line.