# Hide password and other secrets from process table (ps aux) during execution of command

Tags: linux, bash, passwords

Whichever command i execute using password and other secrets that appears/display while doing `ps aux`.

For example: i want to connect with mysql db:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -h hostname -u username --password=password dbname
```

another command:

```
curl https://somesite/$HOST/$USER
```

While executing both command in meanwhile time when i do "ps aux" which display secrets as Hostname and password in process table.

**What's best way to hide secrets from process table.?**

As i know `hidepid=2` hide process from other user which actually is not my solution of above problem.

Comment: `echo $SECRET | command` did you try?

Comment: Very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830823/hiding-secret-from-command-line-parameter-on-unix

Comment: echo $SECRET | command  this won't work as i need to hide from process table (when do ps aux).