# Hide password from ps table, when sending as argument to java program

Tags: java, bash

I take username and password as input in bash script and then have to pass it to java program, but the problem is, anyone can see the username & password using `ps -f`, I read some post to read from stdin and pass which will be hidden from process table.

Here is some code snippet I'm trying with:

```
readSecrets() {
  read -p "Username: " username
  IFS= read -s -p "Password: " password
  echo
  if [[ -z "$username" || -z "$password" ]] ; then
    echo "!!Error!! Username and Password are mandatory."
    exit 0
  fi
}


nohup java -jar $JAR_FILE START $username $password > logFile.log 2>&1 &
```

How can I hide pass from `ps` command and send securily to java program ?

Comment: You have to NOT pass this secrets as *arguments*! Use another way, like *STDIN*, avoid ENVIRONMENT variables too!!

Comment: Also, there are so many other ways to read out the full command including its arguments, that even if you did manage to hide the password from `ps`'s output, it's still out there and visible. Therefore just avoid passing it as an argument.

Comment: Proper security lies server-side, not client-side

Comment: Have a look at [this post on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/592941/142978) and/or [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3830823/1765658)